# SUM and GROUP BY uniqued values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

assume we have a table `inspections`:

```
Table:  inspections
Date        Location_A  Location_B  Location_C  Duration
2020-01-01  User01      User02      User03      10
2020-01-02  User01      User03      User04      20
2020-01-03  User02      User03      User02      10
2020-01-04  User03      User01      User02      30
2020-01-05  User05      User01      User04      40
```

The column `Location_A`, `Location_B` and `Location_C` are using the same codelist/dimension table `users`:

```
Table: users
ID      Name
User01  Jack
User02  Anna
User03  Henry
User04  Paul
User05  Rose
```

I want to SUM specific column `duration` for each `User` and to accomplish that I create 3 `GROUP BY` subqueries for each `Location_` and append it using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t1.user, SUM(t1.total_duration) tot_duration
FROM 
(
    (SELECT Location_A user, SUM(Duration) total_duration FROM inspections GROUP BY Location_A)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT Location_B user, SUM(Duration) total_duration FROM inspections GROUP BY Location_B)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT Location_C user, SUM(Duration) total_duration FROM inspections GROUP BY Location_C)
) t1
```

But, there will be problem as the number of column grows, the more sub queries will be incorporated.
Any solution for that?

Comment: `But, there will be problem as the number of column grows, the more sub queries will be incorporated. Any solution for that?` , Yes, normalize the data to save more pain

Comment: This is the result of a poor database design, simply normalise the data and your query becomes trivial. Your query as written has numerous issues and should not even run.

Comment: `SELECT user, .. FROM inspections ..`  - I see no `user` column in the table.

Comment: What dbms are you using, sql is a language, different dbms have different functions

Comment: Please specify the database you are using (MS_SQL, MySql, etc...)

Comment: Yeah I aware that the database design is poor, but the point I want to highlight is is there any way to combine all unique values (not concatenated) from multiple columns into one column?

Comment: Another case table like a `calls` table with three columns `caller`, `callee`, `duration`, a user can act either as a `caller` or `callee`, then how you get total `duration` per user regardless the act? Is there any way other than using above solution?

Answer (score 2):

This can potentially be resolved by slightly changing the database structure to something that supports these type of queries.

Instead of having location a, b, c as columns and the userid as value, consider having a column Location and A column User.

That way you can easily group by location, userid and do a sum without having to adjust the query when more locations are added.

So your table would look like:

```
Table:  inspections
    Date        Location    User    Duration
    2020-01-01      A       User01      10
    2020-01-02      A       User01      20
    2020-01-03      B       User02      10
    2020-01-04      C       User03      30
    2020-01-05      B       User05      40
```

You would have more rows but it should still be quite easily searchable especially if you use foreign keys on the userId.

This would allow for a query like:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Duration) FROM inspections GROUP BY Location, User
```

**Not only does this mean you never need to change the query, if you add more locations, it also means you don't need to change the database structure whenever you add a location.**

Answer (score 0):

You marked your database as sql-server - that means you can use the built-in function `UNPIVOT`. It does not solve your problem completely, but it might be able to ease the script writing part.

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(Duration) as Duration
FROM Inspections i
UNPIVOT
(UserID FOR Location IN (Location_A, Location_B, Location_C)) as unpvt 
GROUP BY UserID
```

In this case you won't have to write subqueries for each column but just specify column names as they appear.
The returned result of the query you can see in a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c00d76/26/0:)